# Illustrator plugin area

Tags: javascript, plugins, adobe-illustrator

I would like to know what exactly the .area in the following code is giving me:

```
alert("Area & Length \nArea: " + (Math.abs(app.activeDocument.selection[0].area).toFixed(3)) + "\nLength: " + (app.activeDocument.selection[0].length).toFixed(3));
```

I know it gives me an area but in what unit (pixels?). The original code divides the area value/5184 (72*72) which should be ppi value. The documentation did not contain any of this:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question, till now I do not know that length and area property exists in Illustrator. And I figure it out what they are

If selected item is

**Rectangle**

```
var w = app.activeDocument.selection[0].width;
var h = app.activeDocument.selection[0].height;
var length = w + w + h + h;
var area = w * h;
```

**For ellipse/circle**

```
var r = (app.activeDocument.selection[0].width);
var area = π * r * r = 3.14 * r * r;
var length = 2 * pie * r = 2 * 3.14 * r;
```

Basically, it is similar to Maths, it uses area and perimeter(length), based on the shape of the selected objects. Here π is that we used in mathematics.

Hope this will help you.